# Room: how to check whether row exists

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my repository class, I want to fetch data only if none exists in a Room table. How to check whether any row exists in a table?

Comment: I do not know if there is an elegant way to do so in room . But you can query the row and check for null result . Or you can use `COUNT()`.  If no row exist count will be 0.

Comment: if you have your DAO with Rx as `interface MyDao { @Query("SELECT * FROM myTable") fun getAllEntries() : Single<List<Entries>>` and then in your repo you can have a `flatMap{ if (it.isEmpty()) { .. } else { .. } }` for the subscription call for manipulating your data constructs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ADM suggested, you might get lucky using `COUNT()` to count the actual rows in a table.

However, I would recommend just fetching the data anyway - if none exists Room will simply return an empty list, and this should not be less efficient than asking for the row count (if it's `0` anyway).

As a plus you will have less code to write to get the functionality you want! :-)

Comment: The thing is if I am asking for an RxJava `Observable`, nothing would happen if none exists

Comment: You don't have to use `Observable`, you can use `Single` or `Maybe`

Comment: But if I have lots of records in my table the "EXISTS" query would be a lot more efficient than fetching everything.

Comment: @mreichelt, what happens if return type of function is nonnull pojo type and row does not exist.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB If the row doesn't exist, it will still return an empty list, regardless of whether the pojo is nullable or not. It won't return a list of null, just an empty list.

Answer (score 122):

Use `EXISTS` operator, and return 1 means `true` and 0 means `false`.

If you want to check some specific row and some condition, do this trick:

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id = :id)")
fun isRowIsExist(id : Int) : Boolean
```

Or simple use this:

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableName)")
fun isExists(): Boolean
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `EXISTS` operator and return just `Boolean`:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table)")
fun hasItem(): Boolean
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details how to use this solution?